Can anyone do Surya araghya, and can it be done during eclipse
Namaskar,
Due to my chart, I was advised to do Surya araghya after sunrise. Can anyone (also non brahmins) do them.
Was told to chant 'Om Suryaya Namah, Om Bhaskaraya Namah & Om Adityaya Namah'.
As well as to add red flower, red sandalwood and jaggery into the water.
Is this the right way.
And can this be performed daily including during solar eclipses. If not what are days one should not perform it.
Thank you.

You should consult the person who told you to do this. Wouldn't that be better? Afterall, that individual is the one who has advised this. If you believe in the ability of that person, then follow it. Why believe that you should do it, but not believe the "how" and inquire here?

Hi, the person is no longer reachable. Hence posted this question here.

Okay. Thanks for informing me and adding that bit of context. I apologize if my question appeared a bit rude. It was meant to be a genuine question. Although it doesn't appear like that now that I re-read it.
